# HTML5 setCustomValidation fails on Else

Tags: javascript, html, validation

i've this code:

```
function checkPassword(pass1, pass2) {
var p1 = document.getElementById(pass1)
var p2 = document.getElementById(pass2)
if (p1.value != p2.value) {
    p2.setCustomValidity('verifiez que vous avez ecrit le meme mot de passe');
} else {
    p2.setCustomValidity('')
}}

function Banned(password) {
pas = document.getElementById(password)
ban_list = ["111111", "11111111", ...]
for (var i = 0; i < ban_list.length; i++) {
    if (pas.value == ban_list[i]) {
    pas.setCustomValidity("Mot de Passe Facile, Veuillez le changer")
   } else
    {
      pas.setCustomValidity("")}
}}
```

html:(the even is `OnBlur`)

```
<label for="pass1">Votre mot de passe</label>
<input class="keyboardInput" id="pass1" name="pass1" type="password" required onkeypress="checkCapsLock(event);" placeholder="" pattern=".{6,}" title="" onblur="checkPassword('pass1','pass2'); Banned('pass1')">
<label for="pass2">Confirmez le</label>
<input class="keyboardInput" id="pass2" name="pass2" type='password' required onkeypress="checkCapsLock(event);" placeholder="" onblur="checkPassword('pass1','pass2'); Banned('pass1')" title="">
```

Vous avez activé la touche majiscule

the first code works, if i set two different passwords, it will alert me, if i modify it, the alert disappear.
but in the second (Banned), it will not work (the user is not warned), and if i remove the Else part, it will work, but if it will detect a word that is in the list, it will never disappear even if the user modify the value with a string that dident belong to the list.

what is  the problem?

Comment: What does "will not work" mean? Is there an error?

Comment: no, the browser will not alert the user that the password is in the banned list

Comment: how is `Banned` being called?

Comment: i'll put the html, sorry

Comment: a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) would be the ideal

Comment: i've added the html code, the warning will not work, but  if you remove the else statement it will work but never disappear!

Comment: This doesn't work in my browser (Chrome 27). Apparently, Chrome doesn't set the default red border and message for `setCustomValidity()`. Maybe you should solve that first...

Comment: but why it did work on `checkPassword()` and `Banned() without else statement`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not exit the function when a condition is met, i.e. a password is on the ban list. What you want is something more like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < ban_list.length; i++) {
  if (pas.value == ban_list[i]) {
    pas.setCustomValidity("Mot de Passe Facile, Veuillez le changer");
    return;
  }
}
pas.setCustomValidity("");
```

That way you will always get your alert if a password is on the ban list and the alert will disappear if it's not. Mind the position of `pas.setCustomValidity("");` - it's outside the loop.

Comment: thank you! that worked! but why the `pas.setCustomValidity("");` is outside the loop?

Comment: You only want no alert if the password matches **none** of the words on the ban list and you only know that **after** going through all those words. This is the reason why the alert never appeared in your example: If the password was not the last word was on the list, then no alert was set, because the check happened after **every** word,  inside the loop.

Comment: ah, i see, because what i did is following the concept of `checkPassword()` which used `if...else` but there is no loop. thank you again :)